# How to know what component was created using React Router?

Tags: react-router

I have the following routes:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute components={Home}/>
    <Route path="/blog/:blogNo/:filter" component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/blog/:blogNo" component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/:filter" component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/all" component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/terms" component={Terms}/>
    <Route path="/privacy" component={Privacy}/>
    <Route path="/news/:newsNo" component={News}/>
    <Route path="/list/:listNo" component={List}/>
</Route>
```

Notice 4 of the routes are Home. In the render of my App.js I want to figure out which component is created, i.e. Home, News, Terms, Privacy, or List.

I'm trying to use `this.context.router.isActive("")` but I'm not sure how to pass a splat or wildcard like `:filter` or `:blogNo` to the function.

How do I know which component is created in React Router?

Note I am using react router 2.0.0

Comment: you could just do `this.props.children.type.name`, that would give you the name of the component

Comment: @knowbody I tried `this.props.children.type.displayName` but in production I found that my code wasn't being run. I assume that might be optimized out in production

Comment: what are you trying to do, probably there is another way

Comment: I have a component in `App` that is a `mobileMenu`. Since it is a mobile menu and global regardless of page, I want different functionality depending on what page it is. Hence in `App` I have a function that checks the current route and if it is Home I do one thing (namely, filter my blogs by tag) and when in another page I simply reroute to a Route with a filter. Hence the reroute handles the filtering for me. Note that the mobileMenu can't be imported directly into Home or List or Privacy, because I want that menu container OUTSIDE of the Home, List, Privacy container etc for css purposes

Comment: How's your search for an answer coming along? Have the same problem right now.

Comment: @index https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/637 (at the bottom) mentions that React router 3.0 won't have to deal with this issue. However since it isn't out yet, for my use case I simply passed a prop down to each child to indicate which page I am on.

Comment: I see. Same here. I just passed the `params={this.props.params}` and appended it to the `router.isActive` method. Hehe. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For your menu example, you'll want to follow the [named components](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/eb382aa0b105b6e4a602d89e83aa70a2847e1fae/docs/API.md#named-components) documentation. That pattern is designed to allow having a separate menu component, exactly as you've described your situation.

Comment: how does that tell me the name of the component? this.props.main can either be Users or Groups in that example.